# Can SQLAlchemy secondary tables be db.Model instances?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a Flask-SQLAlchemy project and I've implemented a nice JSON serialization method that applies to my SQLAlchemy models. After querying the DB, I can then easily present that data via a REST API. When I'm using `secondary` tables for many-to-many relationships, those tables are instances of `db.Table`, like so:

```
elections_voters = db.Table(
    'elections_voters',
    db.metadata,
    db.Column('election_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('elections.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
)

class Election(MyModel):
    __tablename__ = 'elections'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('election_id_seq'), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    voters = db.relationship('User', secondary=elections_voters, backref='electionsVoting')
```

Let's say I wanted an API that presented just a list of voters for a particular election. I'd do something like `Election.query.get_or_404(election_id)`, then return `election.voters.mycustomserialize()`, as `voters` would be populated by SQLAlchemy. However, it's not an instance of `db.Model` like its parent, so I can't use my serializing method on that child.

Is there a way to set up my models such that the `elections_voters` secondary table is a full instance of `db.Model` rather than just `db.Table`, and is that wise? My serialization method needs access to the column names, which is why I haven't just split it out into a standalone method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over-thinking it:

In this case, `elections.voters` is just a list, not a model instance. I can just use list comprehension to handle the serializing.

Also, there's [Association Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#association-pattern) that do what I described, but I don't think I'll need them.